# Are there any cameras that take photos with a large resolution (over 20Mb) and work with Raspberry Pi?

Tags: camera, image, webcam

I need for a work project to take photos using raspberry pi and a camera that costs less than 500$ and the resolution should be over 20Mb. I did not find any camera with larger resolution than 12Mb ready to be used with raspberry pi.
Can anyone help?

Thank you!

Comment: USB cameras should be fine as long as they do not require special drivers (generally they do not, as it is a standardized protocol).

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but I am not able to find any USB camera with over 20Mb resolution. Any help would be greatly appreciated